# MassTransit message processing concurency

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to solve the problem using MassTransit, and I cannot find the right approach. I will try to explain the scenario in more detail. Our system has the ability to import a huge amount of data (records). On one side is API facade. Facade generates a huge amount of specific messages into the system using MassTransit. Processing messages could mean more things. For example (Create record, Update Record, Do a business operation with the record, ...). For some scenarios, for example, the Update, must be concurrency achieved. That means, if there are more Update messages that work with specific RecordID, do not allow processing more messages than one! With this approach, we would like to avoid transaction locking on DB side. Using message partitioning, we solve the problem of concurrency. The disadvantage is, that only one point of execution (process instance) must exist to achieve message concurrency locking,
Apart from described solution, what is the solution you would use?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to keep in mind that publish-subscribe with queues won't guarantee ordered processing even if you remove concurrency entirely. For example, an RMQ cluster can get into a partitioned state, then recover, and then you might get one message twice, and the second message might come much later than anticipated. Also, the majority of message brokers give you "at least once" delivery, which means you can get one message more than once. With this in mind, it's a good idea to ensure that your message processing consumers are able to ensure idempotence.

With MassTransit, you can only mitigate the issue by using the partitioner filter. In the docs you only find the partitioner mentioned in [Saga Guidelines](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/guidance.html), but it's the same concept - avoid concurrent processing of messages with the same value in a particular field.

However, partitioning only happens within the service instance, which means that it won't work if you have multiple instances of the same service running (competing consumers).

If you want linearized and sequential message processing, you'd need to use an event log-style infrastructure. As it doesn't exactly fit the core MassTransit model, it's supported as [Riders](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/riders/). There, you can choose between Azure Event Hub of Kafka. Remember that those aren't brokers but event logs, so although you can increase the overall performance by using multiple partitions, consumers for each partition run independently. If one consumer won't be able to process messages from its partition, the partition would stop processing messages entirely. Of course, you'd need to use those ids, which you want to linearized, as partition keys.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Message partitioning is the approach we are using now. But I see the limitations regarding one instance. The problem is, that we would like to be ready for scalability and this approach is a blocker.